# Not able to use Snippet in javascript

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

i created this alert snippet .
But somehow it's not working for `Javascript`.
I hope i got the credentials right.
Here is the snippet

```
    <snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>ale</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.JavaScript</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every other example I see for JavaScript uses `source.js`, not `source.JavaScript`

**Edit**: Here's a list https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378 -- can't find it in official documentation.  JavaScript is `source.js` according to this.